# Who called a method?

Tags: java

I have a code:

```
abstract void run();

public void start() {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName());
    try {
        run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn(e.getMessage());
    }       
}
```

I can execute `start()` for example:

```
object1.start();
object2.start();
object3.start();
```

How can I check in `start()` which object (name object) started the method `start()`?

Comment: [this keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) refers to the current instance that called your method.. You can play with it..

Comment: Try to use this.className(); this should work for you.

Comment: @Rohit, `this` only refers to the current instance. His method is public, it could be called externally. Your comment is completely off the mark.

Comment: What information you exactly want to have about the object??

Comment: You can put a name field and set it while creating the object. Use that to identify the object.

Comment: @PawanSharma.. You mean `this.getClass()`??

Answer (score 2):

There is no automatic way to do this; objects in Java don't have to have a name.

One solution is:

```
public void start(String name) {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(name);
}
```

This works because a logger can have an arbitrary name. Many loggers use the class's name because that's a simple + automatic way to name loggers. But that's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're trying to get "object1", "object2" and "object3" as the names (it's not clear), there are two things you ought to be aware of:

- Those are *variables*, not *objects*. Multiple variables with different names could refer to the same object.
- Objects don't generally have names - you can add your own `name` field, but you'll have to do that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to get the string `"object1"`: this is logically not sensible. This is the name of a *variable* not the object it *refers* to, and does not exist at runtime. In fact, the compiler *may* optimize it away completely. Plus, it is ambiguous:

Consider the following code:

```
object2 = object1;
object2.start();
```

Should the instance now see the name `"object1"` or `"object2"`? It is *both*!

If you want your objects to have a "name", use a self-managed field to store it.

```
object1.setName("object2");
```

or do the same in the constructor:

```
MyObject object1 = new MyObject("object1");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new Exception().getStackTrace()[1]
```

see [StackTraceElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the name of the variable at runtime, if that is what you want

I would start the Log outside the start() method

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(object1);
object1.start(log);
```

Then your start() method will look like this:

```
public void start(Logger log) {    
    try {
        run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn(e.getMessage());
    }       
}
```

Or, if you can't change the start() signature:

```
Logger log;
public void setLogger(Logger log){
    this.log = log;
}
public void start() {    
    try {
        run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn(e.getMessage());
    }       
}
```

Then:

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(object1);
object1.setLogger(log);
object1.start();
```